# Button in a TableView in a ScrollView not triggering

Tags: swift, xcode, button, tableview, scrollview

I have 2 tableViews in a ScrollView:

1. The tableViews can't be scrolled and will show all rows
2. Both tableViews have custom cells with buttons
3. Pressing a button from TableView2 will add a row to TableView1

**The Problem:**

1) It initially works, pressing a button from TableView2 will perform a service call and then add a cell to TableView1.

2) However I've noticed that once TableView1 expands to take up the height of the screen and I scroll down to access TableView2, pressing the button on TableView2 no longer registers anything. It doesn't fire the action at all. This is an idea of what I think might be the problem but am not sure.

[image]

**Some Code**

```
extension MyFeedViewController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if tableView == self.tableView1
    {
        return tableView1Array.count
    }
    else
    {
        return tableView2Array.count
    }

}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if tableView == self.tableView1
    {
        let cell:TableView1Cell = self.tableView1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableView1Cell", for: indexPath) as! cell:TableView1Cell


        cell.updateCell(withObject:)
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell

    }
    else
    {
        let cell:TableView2Cell = self.tableView2.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableView2Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableView2Cell

        cell.updateCell(withObject:withType)
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    if tableView == self.tableView1
    {
        return CGFloat(80)
    }
    else
    {
        return CGFloat(60)
    }
}
}
```

Upon getting a successful response from the server, I trigger the recalculation of my scrollView like this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    refreshTableHeights()
}

//Called when a success server call is made
func refreshTableHeights()
{
    //Update table height
    if tableView1Array.count > 0
    {
        tableView1HeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(tableView1Array.count * 80)
    }
    else
    {
        tableView1HeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(80)
    }

    if tableView2Array.count > 0
    {
        tableView2HeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(tableView2Array.count * 60)
    }
    else
    {
        tableView2HeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(60)
    }

    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    //Set content view
    let extraSpace = CGFloat(200)
    contentView.frame.size.height = tableView1.frame.size.height + tableView2.frame.size.height + extraSpace
    scrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size
}
```

**Some other notes:**

1. The table heights are fixed in my IB so am manually changing the height constraints of the tableViews by code.
2. The buttons with their IBActions are defined in their custom cells. Pressing a button from TableView 2 will trigger a delegate call back to my VC to make a service call.

   Would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction as I'm at a lost. Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific on why you are updating the table view height manually? Also it would be helpful to see how your custom cell class looks like

Comment: capture your interface by running it in simulator. See it button is in the frame of its superview or not. touch actions on view doesn't respond if view is outside its superview.

Comment: @Naresh thank you that was my issue. I had a constraint on my contentview which was resetting the contentview height as the scroll view was scrolled.

Comment: You're welcome, I am writing it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Capture your interface by running it in simulator.
See if the button is in the frame of its superview or not, touch actions on view doesn't respond if view is outside its superview.